# Why is it allowed to intersect primitives and objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Why is the following not yielding `never`?

```
type test = string & {name: string}
```

Is it because primitive types are not nominal?

Comment: They get boxed by JS anyway (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects), `string` and `String` both refer to the object type.

Comment: Well. `string` is a *subtype* of `String` (TS will complain if you assign a value of type `String` to a variable of type `string`), but yeah, it has all the apparent members of the `String` interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler does not always aggressively reduce impossible types to `never`.

Often it's not worth the effort, especially if it would involve checking for conflicting properties and subproperties; see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42324#issuecomment-759771519) on microsoft/TypeScript#42324, for an example of how such aggressive reduction could kill performance: "Property resolution is *deferred*; if a property of a type is never needed to be computed, it simply isn't."

Other times, these impossible types are actually useful in and of themselves.  The specific case of intersections of objects with primitive types is in fact used in a technique known as ["branded primitives"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  This allows you to create "nominal" types for primitives that can be distinguished from each other by the compiler.  A `string` is a `string`, but a `string & {__brand: "A"}` is *not* a `string & {__brand: "B"}`. Never mind that at runtime an actual `string` will not have a `__brand` property; we can just lie to the compiler via [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and pretend that we have two different `string` types that can't be mutually assigned.  It's a small abuse of the structural typing system to allow us to simulate nominal typing (see [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202)).

If we were to insist that `string & {__brand: "A"}` should be reduced to `never` because no values can match it, we would lose the ability to create such branded primitives.  This might have been acceptable at some point, but they are used enough in real world code (including the [compiler itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6ed344f2c8b66935ace4a2cc78efd7618840a248/src/compiler/types.ts#L2-L4)) that it would be a breaking change to do so.

Comment: Is it possible to have generic that checks if type can be reduced to never?