# What is the difference between string and string intersected with the empty object in typescript

Tags: typescript

### Background

I noticed that [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com/) uses this type:

```js
type ColorScheme = (string & {}) | "whiteAlpha" | "blackAlpha" | "gray" | "red" | "orange" | "yellow" | "green" | "teal" | "blue" | "cyan" | "purple" | "pink" | "linkedin" | "facebook" | "messenger" | "whatsapp" | "twitter" | "telegram" | undefined
```

My initial thought was that maybe the `(string & {})` tricked autocompletion into working which appears to be correct based on my observations:

```js
// Has autocompletion
type Test = (string & {}) | "blue";
let x: Test = "blue"

// Doesn't have autocompletion
type Test2 = string | "blue";
let y: Test2 = "blue"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAkEMGdUhXALgewMbILYAcA2BTRAS2QDsAoRATyz1ABU9pFQBeUACiYCdCSBzUADJQAbwC+ASlAAfUACIARjnh45AbjL5mADwBc9RszaLlqsmRCgAIskYkA5MwAWkAG60EKdNi3FyVGgMmACZWUG5eAVkTFXVNAlBKfQYQsJjVIA)

### The Question

Why in the world is there a difference between `string` and `(string & {})`? From my understanding, the `{}` type represents any value except `null | undefined` so a string is a subset of that and by definition, if `A ⊂ B` then `A ∪ B = A` right? Maybe I'm crazy but this behavior seems really strange. Thanks!

Comment: `string & {} | "s"` won't get reduced to `string`, but `string | "s"` will. `string & Record<never, never>` behaves the same.

Comment: @caTS yeah, but any idea why?

Comment: What's the actual question?  The title asks for "the purpose" which is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047551/typescript-union-of-string-and-string-literals .  The question asks for why there is a *difference* between `string` and `string & {}` and the answer is different.  Could you make sure the title and body clearly ask the same question?

Comment: Ok fixed @jcalz I was having a hard time squeezing it down into a title, but I just bit the bullet and made a long title (:

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908355/why-is-it-allowed-to-intersect-primitives-and-objects-in-typescript except it's the flip side where you put a property in the object.  The answer is essentially the same; TS doesn't aggressively reduce everything it theoretically could reduce, and in this specific case it stays unreduced to support branded primitives.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of that, or else I'll write up an answer here that is almost the same